# Getting invalid argument from semop

Tags: linux, process, semaphore

I've set(semget + init to 1) a semaphore in process A. Forked A, and got B.

Forked B and got C (code of processes B,C is at another .c file, so I am passing the semid as a global integer with extern int semid).

Into the process C code, I try to apply down(semid) and getting "invalid argument" error.
What I am doing in the code for down function is this:

```
struct sembuf sem_d;
sem_d.sem_num = 0;
sem_d.sem_op = -1;
sem_d.sem_flg = 0;
if ( semop(semid, &sem_d, 1) == -1 )
{
    perror("error with down function");
    return -1;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

I've also have reassured that the semid from when the semaphore is initialized is the same before semop.
Also, in process A,B I am using wait(-1).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are allowed to use `semget()` over forks - it's a different process space after all.

`semget()` is part of the old System V semaphores anyway.

I would recommend to switch over to the [POSIX semaphores](http://linux.die.net/man/7/sem_overview) - `sem_open()`, `sem_wait()` and friends and use named semaphores. Then open the same semaphore names in each process.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be allowed? What would be the problem? (The semaphores IDs are global variables, and semget has been used before all fork calls). Also, I am using semop, not semget. (We actually have an assignment and we have to use System V semaphores :/)

Comment: a fork is copy-on-write. So unless the semaphore is located in an area that stays shared, it is duplicated upon the fork and the first use afterwards. So, how is it going to stay in sync?

Comment: I am getting all the semaphores before any fork is called. So, using as global variables the semids and operating on the any of them using semop is working fine. I found out what was wrong. The mother process was being terminated before the child processes exited. So I was trying to operate on a semaphore that was deleted at the end of the mother process. I thought that with wait(-1) it would be ok..But it needed wait(NULL) afterall.